# MySQL Workbench Synchronization False Positives

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have synchronized a table between a model and a live server database in Workbench, but every time I rerun the "Synchronize With Any Source..." wizard, Workbench detects (falsely) that there is a difference between the model and the server for that table and wants to execute the exact same SQL query.

The SQL in this case is the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`user_info`
CHANGE COLUMN `last_update` `last_update` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This statement has already been executed in my first run of the Wizard, and I can see that the table `user_info` is up to date on the live server. Why does it keep detecting it as a difference? Is it a known bug with MySQL Workbench or something...?

Comment: have you re-launched the wizard as it might be reading from some cached file which may have generated at first run.

Comment: Yes, a couple of times.. the weird thing is everytime I run the wizard it says that all the SQL was executed successfully

Comment: make sure collations are same as well

Comment: I checked the collations. They are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bug. Some of the change detection is not catching this specific case (or interpreting it wrongly). Best is to file a bug report (http://bugs.mysql.com).